# Model not found after deploying to hosting Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, model

[image: Image for the error]Laravel App\Model class not found everything is correct its working fine on a local server but giving error or hosting. It's a shared hosting

Comment: Can you provide your `Model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your local environment is `Windows` while live server is `Linux`. In `Linux` server case sensitive rules can't be bypassed but in `Windows` you can.

Change:

```
App\models\Company
```

To:

```
App\Models\Company
```

Comment: If so, please mark the answer as accepted so that other people can find it useful. Thanks @AbhijeetGupta